# What is the meaning "love someone deliberately"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "deliberately" in this context?

"I take you to be mine in love. I promise to love you deliberately each day, to feel your joy and sorrow as my own"
(From the book "Option B". This is the vows a bride and her groom recited)

I've read this book 3 times but I cannot understand the meaning "deliberately" although I tried to look up the dictionary and googled it.

Can you help me?

Comment: This is from self-written Jewish wedding vows quoted in "Option B: Facing Adversity, Building Resilience, and Finding Joy" by Sheryl Sandberg, Adam Grant. I suspect that it means "I promise to love you every day consciously, intentionally, and on purpose".

Comment: Ah sorry! each *day.